# Django: Searchable form field for ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, django-forms

Say I have model **A** which has a `ManyToMany` attribute joining it to model **B**. When a user creates a model **A**, via some forms, they are appropriately presented with a `MultipleChoiceField` containing all model **B** objects.

Now, there are a **lot** of model **B** objects. Is there a way to make thi s `MultipleChoiceField` searchable? Ideally I'd like to have something like this:

[image]

Where each [+] represents a choice in some particular attribute of **B**.

How could I go about achieving this?

Comment: You might want to look at apps like this one: https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2